# Convert to multiple possible types?

Tags: c#

I've seen the following code on the internet. Can anyone explain to me what it does? If my title is wrong, I'll change it if I get a correct answer:

```
public static void Calculate(float amount)
{
   object amountRef = amount;
   int balance = (int)(float)amountRef;
   Console.WriteLine(balance);
};
```

What does `(int)(float)` do exactly? Its difficult to find explanation on the internet.

Comment: I know its about casting, but why there two possible types int + float?

Comment: First casts it to float, then casts the result to int.

Comment: Boxing `amount` and then unboxing it back to `float` looks pretty redundant. The rest - is just truncation of `float` by casting to `int`.

Comment: @Dirk I was also thinking about something like you say. ty

Comment: Maybe I miss something here but why not to just cast `amount` to int without boxing it? Or maybe it is just a sample piece of code with no meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is about [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

If you save your `float` in an `object` (which is boxing), you need to unbox it with the **original type first**. Than your program cast it to `int`.

That's why you can't say;

```
object amountRef = amount;
int balance = (int)amountRef;
```

You will get;

> Specified cast is not valid. Error: Incorrect unboxing

Comment: Exactly. The first "cast" is an unboxing conversion from `object` to `float`. That involves following the object reference, finding the value and putting it on the call stack (or in a CPU register or where ever). The second "cast" is a numeric conversion from floating-point representation to signed (2's complement) integer representation. It involves finding a new binary representation. Precision may be lost, or the result may be strange due to the number being too huge for an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You're overthinking this (if you're already aware of the purpose casting serves).

A couple of extra parentheses may make it clearer:

```
(int)((float)amountRef)
```

`amountRef` is cast to a `float`, this new `float` is then cast to an `int`.

Comment: No problem. You'd benefit from also looking into boxing and unboxing as Soner suggests, if you're not already familiar with the process.